# If I get laid off after moving to a new state, will I be eligible for unemployment benefits from my old state?

Tags: united-states, unemployment

I have worked in `Pennslylvania` for the past 5 years, but I'm moving to `Florida`.

If I get laid off, will I be eligible for `PA` unemployment benefits?

Comment: what is the order of events: move/layoff or layoff/move. Why are you moving: is the job asking you to move?

Comment: move/layoff. I'm moving for personal reasons. I'll still be working with the same company, but I will be telecommuting.

Comment: @Kevin then they'll pay your FL taxes

Comment: @littleadv what do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're eligible, yes.

We also moved to Florida before my GF was laid off. She had to file with GA. This was a few years back, so I'd check with the FL and PA DOL to be sure.

http://www.workforcesecurity.doleta.gov/unemploy/uifactsheet.asp

"Generally, you should file your claim with the state where you worked. If you worked in a state other than the one where you now live or if you worked in multiple states, the state UI agency where you now live can provide information about how to file your claim with other states."

Check this link as well:

http://work.chron.com/can-draw-unemployment-not-living-state-were-laid-off-10136.html

"You must file for unemployment benefits in the state where you were laid off. This is because your former employer paid unemployment insurance in that state, so the money to cover your benefits is with that state."